Unable to get code chunks to execute in RevealJS presentation
I have been trying to create a revealjs presentation through a Quarto QMD.
However, whenever I have generated the presentation, the code is getting displayed, but I am unable to get it to execute for some reason.
For example, I get the code to create a ggplot figure, not the figure itself. I also added in a simple math calculation with a similar effect.
The chunks execute when I run the code directly.
I have tried changing the YAML header and chunk options, but they have not seemed to solve the problem.
Below is my code in its entirety (I am using a jupyter engine as I was trying to work on a Python issue later, but I wanted to ensure things functioned properly first).
The "" are not a part of my actual code, but a way to try to escape the character for here.
---
title: "Presentation"
format: revealjs
jupyter: python3
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
---

## Slide 1

Here I initiate the environment

```{r}
library(tidyverse)

data1 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1:100),
  y= rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=2.5),
  Condition = sample(c("A","B","C"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
    )

```

## Slide 2

Here should be a code and plot

```{r}
#| eval: true
#| echo: true
#| output: true

data1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, group=Condition, color=Condition)) +
  theme_minimal()+
  geom_point()
  
```

## Slide 3

```{r}
#| eval: true
#| echo: true
#| output: true


1+1
```

I am positive that this is likely a very simple fix, but all sources of help I have found seem to take for granted that the cells execute.
Here is my current R environment
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          3.3                              
year           2024                             
month          02                               
day            29                               
svn rev        86002                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
nickname       Angel Food Cake                  
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reticulate_1.35.0 lubridate_1.9.3   forcats_1.0.0     stringr_1.5.1     dplyr_1.1.4       purrr_1.0.2      
 [7] readr_2.1.5       tidyr_1.3.1       tibble_3.2.1      ggplot2_3.5.0     tidyverse_2.0.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.4        generics_0.1.3    stringi_1.8.3     lattice_0.22-6    hms_1.1.3         magrittr_2.0.3   
 [7] grid_4.3.3        timechange_0.3.0  rprojroot_2.0.4   jsonlite_1.8.8    Matrix_1.6-5      fansi_1.0.6      
[13] scales_1.3.0      cli_3.6.2         rlang_1.1.3       crayon_1.5.2      bit64_4.0.5       munsell_0.5.0    
[19] withr_3.0.0       tools_4.3.3       parallel_4.3.3    tzdb_0.4.0        colorspace_2.1-0  vctrs_0.6.5      
[25] R6_2.5.1          png_0.1-8         lifecycle_1.0.4   fs_1.6.3          bit_4.0.5         usethis_2.2.3    
[31] vroom_1.6.5       pkgconfig_2.0.3   archive_1.1.7     pillar_1.9.0      gtable_0.3.4      glue_1.7.0       
[37] Rcpp_1.0.12       xfun_0.43         tidyselect_1.2.1  rstudioapi_0.16.0 knitr_1.45        farver_2.1.1     
[43] labeling_0.4.3    compiler_4.3.3   
reticulate  lubridate    forcats    stringr      dplyr      purrr      readr      tidyr     tibble    ggplot2  tidyverse 
  "1.35.0"    "1.9.3"    "1.0.0"    "1.5.1"    "1.1.4"    "1.0.2"    "2.1.5"    "1.3.1"    "3.2.1"    "3.5.0"    "2.0.0" 


Based on the docs, you shouldn't need it...but have you tried explicitly putting the engine: jupyter key in your YAML? As an aside, your final chunk only has two backticks at the beginning, instead of three.

Thank you @542goweast! I have added in the engine: jupyter key in the YAML, but it is still not rendering for some reason. (As for the backticks, thank you. I think I might have accidentally deleted it during the copy and paste it up here.)

Hmm. Your MWE seems to work if the engine is commented out (e.g. uses knitr), so it must be due to the jupyter engine itself. The quarto docs don't seem to specify whether you need to set up Jupyter's R kernel yourself (https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel), or if it is supposed to work out-of-the-box with Quarto (ref: https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html#engine-binding). While there seem to be various issues that can arise from one's python setup, it's still probably worth opening an issue at the quarto-cli repo (https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues).
